# What are the implications of not merging a release branch back into develop?

Tags: git, git-flow

We are evaluating git-flow or one-flow strategies. Our `master` branch is latest and we are using feature, release, and hotfix branches. We haven't figured out what to do with a `main` branch yet.

In our API application we have a job template that define the parameters/actions which our workers (applications) perform against our data pipeline. We ran into an issue today where we promoted a release to production but then had to hotfix the same release with a modified template because we discovered our older worker applications (which were not upgraded) were not yet compatible with the latest. Naturally we don't want this template making its way back to the development branch and breaking future releases.

Per GitFlow and OneFlow the release/hotfix branch needs to be merged back into `master` (our develop branch). How would we accomplish this?

Is there a branching strategy where release and hotfix branches are NOT deleted?
What are the implications of keeping the release branch around? How would tags work?

Comment: Merge it back to master and then revert the change on master?

Answer (score 1):

Git flow doesn't address the issue you're having since it assumes a linear progression and doesn't include a support model. If you need to support older versions of the code you should create a new support branch for that version of the software and merge your hotfix back into it.